# Normal projective varieties and its coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-schemes

Let $k[X_0,...,X_n]$ be a polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and $I$ an ideal of $k[X_0,...,X_n]$ generated by homogenous polynomials. Denote by $X$ the projective scheme Proj $k[X_0,...,X_n]/I$. Assume that $k[X_0,...,X_n]/I$ is an integral domain. Is it true that $X$ is a normal scheme if and only if the ring $k[X_0,...,X_n]/I$ is normal?

Comment: This is not true in general. Hartshorne I, ex. 3.18 b) says the twisted quartic in $\{mathbb P}^3$ given by $(x,y,z,w)=(t^4, t^3 u, t u^3 u^4)$ is normal but not projectively normal. Another group of examples is Hartshorne III, ex. 5.6 b (3). where nonsingular curves of type $(a,b)$ on ${\mathbb P}^1 \times {\mathbb P}^1$ are considered.